# Nakano semipositivity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, positivity, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a compact Kaehler manifold.
What is a good, possibly algebraic-geometric, way to think to Nakano semipositivity of holomorphic vector bundles on $X$?

Is the trivial line bundle $\mathcal{O}_X$ Nakano semi-positive as a vector bundle?

Comment: Of course it is Nakano semi-positive : the curvature of $\mathcal O_X$ (equipped with its standard metric) is zero!

Comment: Nakano's positivity is just the ordinary positivity for line bundles.

Comment: Gianni, doesn't my answer satisfy you?

Comment: Yes, it does. I just forgot to accept it. Grazie Simone!

Comment: Of course, it wasn't a sake of reputation... Just I wanted to know if my answer was satisfactory to you... Thanks anyway!

Prego caro!


Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say more properly that nowadays it is not known any satisfactory algebraic description or characterization of the concept of Nakano's positivity for a hermitian vector bundle.

I would like also to add some precisions to Sándor's answer.

First, the positivity in the sense of Nakano is a good notion to obtain vanishing theorems for vector bundles. For instance, we have the following result due to Nakano

**Theorem (Nakano, 1955).** Let $X$ be a compact connected Kähler manifold of dimension $n$ and $E\to X$ a hermitian vector bundle. Then

- if $E\ge_{\text{Nak}}0$, strictly in one point, $H^{n,q}(X,E)=0$, for $q\ge 1$;
- if $E\le_{\text{Nak}}0$, strictly in one point, $H^{p,0}(X,E)=0$, for $p<n$.

On the other hand, Nakano's positivity is not well-behaved with respect to taking duals: we have that $E$ is Griffiths positive if and only if $E^*$ is Griffiths negative, but if we take $H\to\mathbb P^n$ to be the vector bundle of rank $n$ defined by
$$
0\to\mathcal O(-1)\to\underline{\mathbb C}^{n+1}\to H\to 0,
$$
where $\underline{\mathbb C}^{n+1}$ si the trivial vector bundle over $\mathbb P^n$ with fiber $\mathbb C^{n+1}$, then $H$ is Griffiths (semi)positive and $H^*$ is Nakano (semi)negative but $H$ is neither Nakano (semi)positive nor Nakano (semi)negative.

If we look to short exact sequences of vector bundles
$$
0\to S\to E\to Q\to 0,
$$
then the Nakano's negativity of $E$ implies the Nakano's negativity of $S$, but nothing can be said about the Nakano's positivity of $Q$ when $E$ is Nakano positive (the desired property holds if we look instead to Griffiths' positivity).

Of course Nakano's positivity implies the Griffiths' one; the following "partial converse" is due to Demailly and Skoda:

**Theorem (Demailly-Skoda, 1979).** For any hermitian vector bundle $E$, $E>_{\text{Grif}}0$ implies $E\otimes\det E>_{\text{Nak}}0$.

Answer (score 4):

*Nakano (semi-)positivity* is not an algebraic notion. It implies *Griffiths positivity*, which implies *ampleness*. It is known that Griffiths positivity *does not imply* Nakano positivity (an example is the tangent bundle of the complex projective space), but it is not known whether ampleness implies Griffiths positivity.

For more on this see 6.1.D of [Lazarsfeld's book](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-3-540-22534-8). The fact that the tangent bundle of the complex projective space is not Nakano positive follows from a vanishing theorem p.97 of [ibid](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-3-540-22534-8). that fails for it.